# Wave file header has wrong size for an unknown reason

Tags: java, android, binary, hex

I'm trying to save raw pcm audio as Wav file (with Wave header). The problem is my header for an unknown reason is 48-bytes long.`29 00 29 00` bytes are located at the end of the header. Just after writing header (and before) writing raw data to it I check bytes written `Log.i("header", String.valueOf(dos.size()))` and the result is 48 while should be 44.

file header (Hex):

```
52 49 46 46  //"RIFF"
24 90 43 08
57 41 56 45  // "WAVE"
66 6D 74 20  // "fmt "
10 00 00 00
01 00 02 00
44 AC 00 00
10 B1 02 00
04 00 00 00
10 00 00 00
64 61 74 61 // "data"
00 E4 10 02 // raw data size. Decimal 34661376. Looks ok to me.
29 00 29 00 // Where these come from?
```

code:

```
public void writeWav(byte rawAudio[], String filename)   {

    Log.i("data3", String.valueOf(rawAudio.length));

    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    String youFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download/"+filename;
    int myDataSize = rawAudio.length;
    int myChunk2Size =  myDataSize * 2 * 16/8;
    int myChunkSize = 36 + myChunk2Size;


    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(youFilePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    try {

        dos.writeBytes("RIFF");
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray(myChunkSize));
        dos.writeBytes("WAVE");
        dos.writeBytes("fmt ");
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray(16));
        dos.write(intToTwoByteArray(1));
        dos.write(intToTwoByteArray(2));
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray(44100));
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray((44100 * 2 * 16)/8));
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray((2*16)/8));
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray(16));
        dos.writeBytes("data");
        dos.write(intToFourByteArray(myDataSize));
        Log.i("header", String.valueOf(dos.size())); // 48 bytes. Why?
        dos.write(rawAudio);
        Log.i("data output stream", String.valueOf(dos.size()));
        Log.i("myDataSize", String.valueOf(myDataSize));
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private byte[] intToFourByteArray(int i)    {

    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    b[0] = (byte) (i & 0x00FF);
    b[1] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0x000000FF);
    b[2] = (byte) ((i >> 16) & 0x000000FF);
    b[3] = (byte) ((i >> 24) & 0x000000FF);

    // little endian
    Log.i("byte", String.valueOf(b[0]+","+b[1]+","+b[2]+","+b[3]));
    return b;
}

private byte[] intToTwoByteArray(int i)    {

    byte[] b = new byte[2];
    b[0] = (byte) (i & 0x00FF);
    b[1] = (byte) ((i >> 8) & 0x00FF);

    // little endian
    Log.i("byte", String.valueOf(b[0]+","+b[1]));
    return b;
}
```

Comment: `rawAudio[]` is raw pcm audio data, but I don't see neither `rawAudio[0]` nor `rawAudio[1]` in my code.

Comment: `dos.write(rawAudio);` soi what is `rawAudio[0]`, `[1]`,  `[2]` and `[3]` ?

Comment: Ok, `rawAudio[0]`=0x29, `rawAudio[1]`=0x00, `rawAudio[2]`=0x29, `rawAudio[3]`=0x00. But how come it was written before `dos.write(rawAudio)` was called?

Comment: strange, `rawAudio[2]` should be 0x29, not 0x41

Comment: And it was. My mistake. Edited.

Comment: so everything is clear, right?

Comment: Well I still don't know why this data was written before  `dos.write(rawAudio)` was called.

Comment: `Log.i("header", String.valueOf(dos.size()))` is called before `dos.write(rawAudio)`

Comment: 12 * 4 = 48, i dont really know whats your problem - on hex dump you have 12 rows and 13 is `29 00 29 00`

Comment: Yes, but `29 00 29 00` is written before `dos.write(rawAudio)` is called.

Comment: `00 E4 10 02` is written by `dos.write(intToFourByteArray(myDataSize));` and `29 00 29 00 ......` is written by `dos.write(rawAudio)` your `Log.i("header", String.valueOf(dos.size()));` prints `48` which is correct

Comment: But the Log instruction is above `dos.write(rawAudio)` so it is executed before `dos.write(rawAudio)` starts. Then `29 00 29 00 `was not written yet.

Comment: and that's why it logs 48, which is the size of your header, next bytes are raw data

Comment: You're  right. I don't know why i was searching for a problem elsewhere. Thank you very much for your time and patience :)